# Reduce Application size when using NDK

Tags: java, android, kotlin, gradle

I am using cropping library which include ABI filters so when I generate apk or bundle its size is to much unto 308Mb so is there any way to reduce apk size without using ABi Filters.

this is my Gradle default config.

```
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.document.scanner.fast.scan.pdf.create.pdf.test" //com.document.scanner.fast.scan.pdf.create.pdf.editor //com.document.scanner.fast.scan.pdf.create.pdf.test
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0.0"

        ndk {
            abiFilters "armeabi-v7a"
        }
//        splits { //Working But Not on Xiaomi
//            abi {
//                enable true
//                reset()
//                include 'armeabi-v7a', 'arm64_v8a'
//                universalApk false
//            }
//        }

        resConfigs "en"

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used to face this problem, after a while looking for a solution, only using the API filter.

And I use this because it supports most new devices nowadays

```
ndk {
    abiFilters 'arm64-v8a', 'armeabi-v7a'
}
```

Comment: I have added those filter but with this 24Mb size get increase so what if I use only one than it will be fine?

Comment: Please read more information here to understand ABI. https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/abis.. and below is a list of devices including cpu details.  Based on that, you will know which cpu line your application should support https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1mzQZNwnzAONz-PEkjIns4ycRQzZAaVxr4rRvpnUf7fw/edit?usp=drivesdk