# Flutter video_player (better_player) error, x256 and 10bit videos not supported

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-video-player

## History check

I have checked everywhere, but haven't found any solution for this.

## Problem

Currently I am creating an OTT platform for android devices and for Video streaming I am using better_player as a video player for my app, but there are some issues I am facing like, cannot able to change volume of HEVC encoded videos, and cannot able to play x256 10bit videos.

I have also tried flutter_vlc_player and it is working fine with all formats but the majot problem is flutter_vlc_player increased size of apk a lot, from 30MB to 106MB. I won't publish my app to Play store so it will be a problem for me.

## Expecting

I am expecting to play those videos like vlc player in better_player, without any problem, Is there any solution avaialable?

Comment: Have you tried to filter the ABIs (supported CPU architectures) of your app? For a video player that should run on modern devices armv8a is IMHO the only platform you have to support. That should reduce the APK size.

Comment: @Robert but what about some older devices?

Comment: To my experience older devices have neither x256 hardware decoding not 10bit support so they have to decode a video by the CPU, but the CPU is too weak to decode a video e.g. in 720p in real-time.

Comment: @Robert Is there any way to build APK that supports only two abi, armv8a and armeabi-v7a?

Comment: Any combination you like: https://stackoverflow.com/q/70121045/150978

Comment: @Robert Thanks for the help, With including only both armv8a and armeabi-v7a, the APK size in now half of it, it is now 58MB from 106MB.